# Theory of indexes for query with joins

Tags: mysql, innodb, index-tuning

I found the following talk by Zardosht Kasheff enlightening:

http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Index-SQL

but it only covers the case of simple queries on a single table.

Is there something similar for queries involving multiple tables?  Possibly including GROUP BY?

I'm looking for some theory/guidelines which I can apply to MySQL with the InnoDB storage engine.

Comment: Caution: Kasheff's talk focuses on TokuDb.  _Some_ of his points do not apply to InnoDB.

Comment: Perhaps it was a slightly different version of the talk I watched, but he said up front that his rules/guidelines applied to B-Tree indexes as well as fractal tree indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common mistake is

```
SELECT ... SUM(a.foo) ...
    FROM a
    JOIN b ON ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY a.id
```

When you `JOIN` two tables, you usually get an explosion of the number of rows.  The `SUM` is then done, probably summing up a.foo repeatedly, leading to the 'wrong' (too big) answer.

But that was not what you asked.

A `JOIN` is almost always **executed this way**:

1. Pick a table to start with.  Apply any filtering (`WHERE`).  So far, the single-table rules apply.
2. Move on to another table.  But this time, use "Nested Loop Join".  This means "foreach row from step 1, reach into table 2".

So, the new question you are asking is **how to reach into table 2**?  There is an `ON` clause (assuming it is not a "cross join").  That gives you one (or more) field that should be used in the 'best' index for table 2.  Then use that field, plus any other fields in `WHERE`, together with the single-table rules to construct the optimal index for that `JOIN`.

Since the optimizer might pick a **different order of tables**, or might like to have multiple choices, find the best indexes for each order.

Then **simplify**.

- `INDEX(x), INDEX(x,y)` --> `INDEX(x,y)`
- Don't have indexes with more than, say, 5 fields.
- If you are joining to the `PRIMARY KEY` of table 2, you don't need a longer index.
- Consider "covering" indexes.  (`EXPLAIN` will say "Using index", not to be confused with "Using index condition", which is ICP.)

Here are *some* tips on **how the optimizer thinks** when joining two tables:

- A table *with* a `WHERE` filter will be chosen before one without.
- Other things being 'equal', the *smaller* table will be chosen first.
- Sometimes an `ORDER BY` will be preferred over a `WHERE` in ordering the tables.
- `LIMIT` is rarely a factor, although it probably should be.

My [*cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql) also focuses on single-table; maybe this answer will help me write about `JOINs`.

Comment: Thanks.  Part of my problem is that Kasheff's talk specifically says that this sort of "for each row, look up something in the table" is slow, and you should rather have an index that covers the columns you need so that you can get the results in one go.  It seems this can't be avoided for joined tables, though.  So would it be reasonable to create the indexes for each table more or less independently based on the where clauses (and maybe the "ON" clauses and columns mentioned in the SELECT clause)? What about OUTER joins?

Comment: NLJ is usually the best way to execute a `JOIN` for InnoDB; indexes based on `WHERE` and `ON` are the best way to optimize that.  "... create the indexes ..." - Yes.

Comment: There aren't many different `JOINs`.  The keywords `INNER` and `OUTER` are ignored.  Without an `ON`, you get a `CROSS` join.  `LEFT` may force the order of the tables; `STRAIGHT_JOIN` definitely forces the order.